# Wordpress PayPal IPN inserts only numeric data into the database

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am trying to custom store the transaction data on my wordpress site. The problem is that only the data that is numeric that is `item_number` and `amount` are getting inserted into the database. But no text data are getting inserted into the database. Here is my PayPal IPN script.

```
<?php
include('../../../wp-load.php');

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();

foreach($raw_post_array as $keyval){
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2){
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
  }
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')){
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}

foreach($myPost as $key => $value){
  if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1){
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  }else{
    $value = urlencode($value);
  }
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init('https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');

if($ch == FALSE){
  return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if(strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 || strcasecmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0){
  $entry      = $_POST['item_number']; // INSERTING
  $amount     = $_POST['mc_gross']; // INSERTING
  $membership = $_POST['item_name']; // NOT INSERTING
  $payType    = $_POST['description']; // NOT INSERTING
  $txnid      = $_POST['txn_id']; // NOT INSERTING
  $currency   = $_POST['mc_currency']; // NOT INSERTING
  $status     = $_POST['payment_status']; // NOT INSERTING

  // PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL. DO SOMETHING HERE.

  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(1, $entry)"); // INSERTING
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(2, $membership)"); // NOT INSERTING
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(3, $payType)"); // NOT INSERTING
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(4, $txnid)"); // NOT INSERTING
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(5, $amount)"); // INSERTING
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(6, $currency)"); // NOT INSERTING
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_membership`)VALUES(7, $status)"); // NOT INSERTING


  // $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_payments(`pay_gateway`, `pay_entry`, `pay_membership`, `pay_type`, `pay_txnid`, `pay_amount`, `pay_currency`, `pay_status`)
  //               VALUES('PayPal', $entry, $membership, $payType, $txnid, $amount, $currency, $status)");

}else{
  // PAYMENT UNSUCCESSFUL. DO SOMETHING HERE.
}

?>
```

I never faced such issue before. What can be the issue here? How can I get through this? `pay_membership` is `longtext` datatype. Also, how can I log received post data into file to check what I am receiving as this script is processed in the background?

Comment: You didn’t put quotes around any of these values, so of course it will fail for anything non-numeric.

Comment: _“Also, how can I log received post data into file to check what I am receiving as this script is processed in the background?”_ - encode $_POST as JSON or use var_export, and … write it to a file.

Comment: @CBroe you mean single quotes like this '$membership' ?

Comment: Yes, of course. That text literals in MySQL need to be in quotes, should be basic knowledge, no?

Comment: Oh yes that worked.. Thank you.. I have one more question.. I am getting `payment_status` as `Pending`. How can I confirm if it was `Success` ?

Comment: Is it a new currency for the account? Go into the account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and accept the first payment in that currency.

Comment: @PrestonPHX please refer to my earlier comment. It is solved already.

Comment: What I said is precisely a reply to that comment. If it's not a new currency you'll have to look at other factors for why it is pending. Usually there is a `pending_reason`